# I need to an Elasticsearch Query with subquery

Tags: elasticsearch

I need a help on converting the following sql into elastic query

select * from index1 where column1 not in (select column4 from index1) and column2= Value3.

[image]
Should return third row only

I have tried using scripting language. But I'm relatively new. I unable to get the result

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [SQL search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-search-api.html)
2. You can use [the boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to combine multiple queries.

### Here is an example

```
POST test_sql/_bulk?refresh
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"column1":"1","column2":"value3","column3":"value1","column4":""}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"column1":"2","column2":"value2","column3":"value2","column4":"1"}
{"index":{"_id":"3"}}
{"column1":"3","column2":"value3","column3":"value3","column4":""}


GET test_sql/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "column2": "value3"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "column1": {
              "index": "test_sql",
              "path": "column4",
              "id": "2"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

> This is a search query for Elasticsearch. It looks for
> documents in the "test_sql" index that have a value of "value3" in the
> "column2" field. It also excludes documents that have value in the
> "column1" field that matches the value of the "column4" field in a
> specific document with an ID of "2".

check column4 field value for "_id"=2 => the value is 1.
excludes documents that value equal to 1. "_id"=1 excluded because "column1": "1".

```
The more simple explanation for this query:
If a column4 value is equal to the column1 value exclude the document.
```

Note: In Elasticsearch, it's not possible to exclude more than one field document value with a `terms` query.

[image]

Comment: Based on sub query condition row1,column1 matches with row2,column4. So we need to return only third row. But above query returns first and third row.

Comment: it's only returning the third row.